# Is there a shorthand form to get variables' values with numbered scopes?

Tags: powershell, scope

Is there any shorter way of doing this in **Powershell v2.0**?

```
& { $a = 1 ; & { $a = 2 ; & { get-variable -name a -scope 2 } } }
```

... like, for instance, this?:

```
& { $a = 1 ; & { $a = 2 ; & { $2:a } } }
```

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I'd rather say that it's a question about a programming language if I had to be pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a shortcut for scoping - it appears to be only accessible by using the `-scope` argument.  However, a function could encapsulate the work:

```
function Get-ScopedVariable([string]$name, [int]$scope) {
    Get-Variable -name $name -scope ($scope + 1) # add one for the extra-scope of this function
}
```

Your example would then be shortened to:

```
& { $a = 1 ; & { $a = 2 ; & { Get-ScopedVariable a 2 } } }
```

The function could then be aliased to further shorten it.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I was asking about built-in shortcuts besides aliases, but this answer is the most adequate to the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of default aliases, one of which happens to be `gv` for `Get-Variable`:

```
gv -Name a -Scope 2
```

Furthermore you don't need to supply the `-Name` parameter explicitly as it's inferred to be the first argument:

```
gv a -Scope 2
```

And you don't need to write out the complete parameter name and can shorten it (as long as it remains unambiguous):

```
gv a -s 2
```

Mind you, you shouldn't do this in scripts you intend to distribute but for something quick on the command line this is certainly valid.